# How will Russia benefit geopolitically from the current chilling of the relation between the EU and the U.S.?

Tags: international-relations, geopolitics

How will Russia benefit from the current chilling of the relation between the EU and the U.S.? As you know, the Trump administration is attacking the EU on trade and is also putting pressure on the EU to spend more on the military and threatened to pull out troop out of the EU. How can these moves benefit Russia on the geopolitical stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Trade

Since trade involves a transfer of something to you that you want more than what is transferred from you, it strengthens both parties.  Reducing trade thus weakens both parties.

It is to Russia's advantage for the United States and European Union to be weakened as that leaves Russia in a relatively stronger position.  It is also possible that Russia might get some of the trade that the US would be giving up.

#### Increased military spending

This doesn't help Russia at all.  Presumably it's undesirable.

#### Pull troops out of the EU

If the US pulled its troops out of the EU:

1. The EU would have fewer allied troops in it.
2. It wouldn't be as certain that the US would participate in a military conflict in the EU.  Because if US troops were there, the US would at least have to protect those troops.  But if they're gone, that's no longer an issue.  The US could still participate, but it might not.
3. It would be harder for the US to deploy troops to places like Poland and the Baltic countries.

#### Other reasons

The US and EU disputes may also have little to do with Russia.  Even if they are to Russia's advantage, they could be caused by something else.